# PHP navigation bar include

Tags: php, html

I've been looking to make my navigation bar work on all my pages but it is not showing. I've been using php includes

This is my nav-bar in a "includes" folder:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="nav-bar">
        <div class='logo'>
            <h1>Va Jugar</h1>
        </div>
        <div class='nav-buttons'>
            <nav>
                <a href="index.php">Home</a>
                <a href="stuff.php">stuff</a>
                <a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="login">
            <a class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true" href="login.html" 
title="Login"></a>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the index.php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF -8'>
    <meta name="description" content='...' />
<title>my page</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/style.css'>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <?php include_once ("includes/header.php";) ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I can't find what I'm doing wrong but the result should be the navigation bar showing on the top and nothing shows up for me. Also, can I include the particular nav bar style page too? Or it has to be on the index.html and on one particular style.css file.

Comment: Is there any error in your PHP logs?  When you open the page source in your browser, what's actually there?

Comment: Why do you have the full html, head and body tags in your header.php?

Comment: You're including a complete HTML document in another HTML document. Only include the markup for the actual nav-bar.

Comment: Can you try this:
<?php include_once (__DIR_\_."/includes/header.php";) ?>

Answer (score 2):

Your included file should only contain the source code that you'd put at the place you include it.

You should not have doctype, html, head and body in your included file but only

```
<div class="nav-bar">...</div>
```